How can I get rid of large screensaver movies on macOS 15?
This page implies that right clicking should work but I don't see to find a way to get rid of this from UI. Where is the file located so that I can trash is from cmdline or by other means
Both this:
/Library/Screen\ Savers

And this:
~/Library/Screen\ Savers

Are empty.


Assume these are the default screensavers installed in /System/... ? Don't think you can remove them.

I agree with @nohillside. The page is talking about third-party installed screensavers. You can remove them but you can't remove the Apple screensavers.

Sadly, according to the answers in the comments you have to bear the grunt
of the modern OS flush with tons of useless bells and whistles
made to sell extra ssd storage.
Short of compromising the security of the OS switching off integrity checks there is no way to remove the useless bloat :-[
